# Difference between too and as well

Tags: adverbs

What’s the difference between too and as well at the end of the phrase?
E.g. I like cycling too vs I like cycling as well.

Answer (score 4):

From [espressoenglish](https://www.espressoenglish.net/difference-between-also-too-and-as-well/):

> The only difference is in their placement in the sentence. **Too** and **as well** are used at the end of a sentence. (**As well** is more formal than **too**).

**Too** and **As well** both used to show similarity or sameness. "Too" usually used in the end of sentences while "as well" can come in the middle with "as well as" (similar to "and" or "not only… but also").

An example of "as well as":

- She bought the necklace **as well as** the earrings.

Same example with "as well" and "too":

- She bought the necklace **as well**.
- She bought the necklace **too**.

---

From [dictionary.cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/also-as-well-or-too) (i suggest to read this):

**As well**:

> - Is much more common in speaking than in writing
> - Almost always comes in end position

**Too**:

> - We usually put **too** in end position
> - **Too** can occur immediately after the subject, if it refers directly to the subject. It does not normally occur after a modal or auxiliary verb. We sometimes write commas before and after too:

Example:

- I **too** thought she looked unwell.
- We, **too**, have been very pleased to receive the prize on her behalf.